# Пробуем обойтись без переменной в masm

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Почему у меня не выходит обойтись без переменной ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
include E:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
HeapAlloc PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD
myfree proto :DWORD

.data
hmyHeap dd 0
hConsoleOutput DWORD ?
adres DWORD ?
hMylp1 dd 0

szCALL MACRO sz
        CALL @F
        BYTE sz, NULL
        @@:
    ENDM

.code

main:
        invoke AllocConsole
        invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        mov hConsoleOutput, EAX
invoke GetProcessHeap
mov hmyHeap,eax

invoke HeapAlloc,hmyHeap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,300h
mov hMylp1,eax
szCALL "string"
mov adres, esp
push 7
push adres
push eax
call RtlMoveMemory

mov ebx, [hMylp1]
invoke WriteConsoleA, hConsoleOutput, ebx, 7, 0, 0
invoke HeapFree,hmyHeap,NULL,hMylp1
    ret

end main
```

А вот если это сделать с messagebox, то всё ок

```
    всё одно и тоже что и в коде выше
    ...
    push 0
    push 0
    szCALL "string"
    push 0
    call MessageBox
```

Comment: @Mike так что, всё так очинь плоха? 

Comment: Я не понял почему в случае msgbox вы написали szCALL в нужном месте, что бы он сам положил в стек параметр. А в случае копирования написали непонятно что с регистром esp и переменной. Вот тупо по аналогии с msgbox должно быть что то вроде `push 7; szCALL "string"; push eax; call`

Comment: @MIke спасибо, помогло, точнее заработало, оформите красиво ответ и я поставлю тему как решённую :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Макрос `szCALL` делает довольно хитрый "хак", он определяет непосредственно в сегменте кода область с данными и выполняет `call` на инструкцию, непосредственно следующую за этими данными. Инструкция `call` - это практически `jmp` по указанному адресу, с `push <адрес-след-инструкции>` (т.е. она кладет в стек адрес возврата). В случае с `szCALL` адресом следующей "инструкции" является адрес сформированной строки, который и помещается в стек. Если же мы этот адрес хотим передать как аргумент какой нибудь функции, он как раз и должен оказаться в стеке. Для передачи адреса строки, как аргумента RtlMoveMemory нам просто нужно указать его в правильном месте среди прочих аргументов:

```
push   7
szCALL "string"
push   eax
call   RtlMoveMemory
```

Хотя вызывать функцию WinAPI для того что бы положить в область памяти короткую строчку из 7 байт как то уж "черезчур". Можно было бы написать что то вроде (eax - адрес памяти, куда кладем строку):

```
mov  dword ptr [eax],  "irts"  ; Да, байты на intel платформе в обратном порядке
mov   word ptr [eax+4],"gn"
mov   byte ptr [eax+6],0
```

Comment: Шикарное объяснение 

Comment: Вот при локализации программ без исходников за последний пример хочется убивать компилятор, который так наоптимизировал)

Comment: @insolor Не понял, причем тут какая то оптимизация компилятором, это же ассемблер, причем платформо-специфичный, вся оптимизация руками

Comment: @Mike, я сталкивался со случаями, когда компилятор выдавал такой код. Ну или копирование строки из одного места в памяти в другое несколькими командами mov через регистры. Это все хорошо, выполняется достаточно быстро, но вызывает проблемы, когда хочется более-менее автоматизированно заменять оригинальные строки в бинарнике на другие.